# :select with find_in_batches in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I include a :select clause with find_in_batches. The following throws an error " Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'users.id' in 'field list': .

```
Post.find_in_batches(:batch_size => 100, :select => "users.id, users.name, categories.name, posts.id", :include => [:user, :category]) do |group|
#stuff with group
end
```

Answer (score -31, accepted):

Your life with Rails will be much easier if you just retrieve all of the fields for each model queried, like so:

```
Post.find_in_batches(:batch_size => 100, :include => [:user, :category]) do |post|
   u = post.user
   c = post.category
   # do stuff
end
```

A trimmed select list, as in your question, provides a limited DB performance improvement, but in most cases not enough to be worth the clunkier code.

Comment: OMG.. do not listen to this.. "if you just retrieve all the fields".  We (our processors) pay for traffic... a table of 20 fields times 170,000 records where some fields are varchar(max) and you're only after the ids.  Yeah good idea to pull megs and megs across the database network and fill up our ram with things we don't care about..  It will be easier unless you care in the slightest about performance, and stability.

Comment: Maybe what marshally might have meant to say was that you should avoid premature optimization.  I think you should always have an idea what your rails queries are ultimately going to do and how much load that is going to be, but attempting to squeeze every last piece of performance out in every situation at the cost of developer cycles is probably not optimal either.  There's definitely a balance.

Comment: If you are using find_in_batches to optimise memory, does not make any sense to increase memory getting all fields, if you are not going to use them.

Answer (score 42):

So, if you're considering using find_in_batches it probably means you have a lot of records to go through and you very well might only want select fields to be returned to you from the DB.

In Rails 3/4 you can chain find_in_batches with any other type ActiveRecord::Relation method (or at least, most... I have not tested all of them personally).

This is probably what you're looking for

```
User.select(:id).find_in_batches(:batch_size => 100) do |group|
   # do something with group... 
   # like print all the ids
   puts group.map(&:id)

end
```

If you try this in the console it generates SQL like this...

```
 SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` > 895846) ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 100
```

See more info here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html